# SQL Select and count Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am unsure how to word the question title so it applies more generally (so this probably not a good question for SO). It would only make sense by showing my specific tables and columns.

I have two tables `project` and `project_team`. Each project can have multiple employees working on a specific project.

**project** table:

```
+----------------+------------------+--------+
| project_number | project_name     | deptNo |
+----------------+------------------+--------+
| 1              | Web App          | 1      |
+----------------+------------------+--------+
| 2              | Art History Pres | 2      |
+----------------+------------------+--------+
| 3              | Machine Learning | 1      |
+----------------+------------------+--------+
```

**project_team** table:

```
+----------------+-------------+------------+
| project_number | employee_id | role       |
+----------------+-------------+------------+
| 1              | 1           | Lead Dev   |
+----------------+-------------+------------+
| 2              | 2           | Consultant |
+----------------+-------------+------------+
| 1              | 3           | Frontend   |
+----------------+-------------+------------+
```

The example I am using is asking me to return the project number, project name, and the number of employees who worked on it **by role**.

Here is what I have right now:

```
select role, count(employee_id) from project_team group by role;
```

This should count each employee that are a certain role, if I have done it correctly.

But how do return each project and their roles and the number of supposed employees working in those roles? My first thought was through the use of a join, but I am relatively new to working Databases.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables and then group by the project id, name and role:

```
SELECT   p.project_number, p.project_name, t.role, COUNT(*)
FROM     project p
JOIN     project_team t ON p.project_number = t.project_number
GROUP BY p.project_number, p.project_name, t.role
```

Comment: @Alec `count(*)` counts the number of rows, per group

Comment: yes it is per project per role count(). it is generalized you can write any column name inside count and as it aggregates the no of rows rather you can simply write (*)

Comment: @Himanshu Ahuja so I could use count(employee_id) as well or is there a difference?

Comment: No, there isnt any difference. It will also give you the same o/p

Comment: @Alec `count(employee_id)` will count the rows that have a non-null `employee_id`. Since it probably can't be null, that would have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Using Left Join will give you all the 
projects details (can use). So, the below query gives all the project numbers/names with different roles (x,y,z etc) details.

Your first thought is correct we need a join here as the `project_team` does not have `project_name` etc. Plus, here left join means there may be possibility that all the project numbers might not be available in project_team table. To avoid any missing project numbers I have used `LEFT JOIN`.

```sql
SELECT p.project_number, 
       p.project_name, 
       t.role, 
       Count(t.employee_id) 
FROM   project p 
       LEFT JOIN project_team t 
              ON t.project_number = p.project_number 
GROUP  BY p.project_number, p.project_name, t.role;
```